# trying to count files in a dir and subdirectories without the use of walk

Tags: python

I need to count the files in both the dir path I give and subdir within that path without the use of walk. This is as far as I've gotten:

```
import os

subfolder = True

path = ("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Electronic Arts\\The Sims 4")
num = 0
def countFiles(path, subfolder=True):
    try:
        for entry in os.scandir(path):
            if entry.is_file():
                num += 1
            if entry.is_dir() and subfolder:
                yield countFiles(entry.path, subfolder)
        print (entry)
print (num)
```

Comment: I don't see where you call your function. Did you mean to do `print(countFiles(path))`? or `num = countFiles(path)` before calling `print(num)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os

subfolder = True
num = 0

def countFiles(path, subfolder=True):
    global num
    for entry in os.listdir(path):
        temp_path = os.path.join(path, entry)
        if os.path.isfile(temp_path):
            num += 1
        if os.path.isdir(temp_path) and subfolder:
            countFiles(temp_path, subfolder)
    return num

num = countFiles(path)
```

Comment: Did you read which function they don't want to use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.scandir`

For Python 3.4 or earlier, use `os.listdir`

Comment: this does not help me, thank you though